# Stackoverflow creates different accounts

Tags: support

Stackoverflow creates different accounts for one openId at google on different machines. Is there any way to use one account on all machiches?

Comment: Maybe using that odd `http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` URL? (See http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2008/10/google-moves-towards-single-sign-on.html)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38038

Comment: it just works for me with google's openID from my home and work machine

Answer (score 1):

I use the google openid, and I've never had any of these problems. Are you sure you have a *registered* SO account, rather than just having an unregistered account linked to your google-mail email address?

If you let me know some way of identifying your posts (any clue at all) I'd happily take a peek...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use [myopenid.com](http://myopenid.com) (or another solid provider) instead of the Google OpenID provider.

I am sure there is a way to make the Google provider work, but there have been [issues](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fblog.stackoverflow.com+openid+google) with the Google provider since the start and in my opinion it is not worth the trouble. I have used myopenid.com since I started on StackOverflow in the beta, and I have never had an issue, and I cannot remember the last time I even needed to log in. Things **just work** which is the only way it should be.

Once you have a solid OpenID set up, email team@stackoverflow.com with the accounts you know of, and they can merge them.